# Replace letters dynamic

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace letters in a string based on an array of letters.

What I'm doing so far is

```
var value = '00-.Tday(52)'
if(!textService.containsLettersExcept(value, ['t', '.', '-'])){
    // yay
}

       function containsLettersExcept(text, exceptions){
            console.info('text before : ', text)
            for(var i = 0; i< exceptions.length; i++){
                var char = exceptions[i];
                text = text.replace(/char/gi, '');
            }
            console.info('text : ', text)
            return text.match(/[a-z]/i);
        }
```

This however  tries to remove the string "char" rather than the variable `char` from the string `text`

Comment: `text.replace(new RegExp(char, 'gi'), '');`

Comment: why not pass `[t\.-]` and replace once?

Comment: I want to be able to use it with different arrays ^^

Comment: then you need to escape the values, `.` for example is *any character* from the perspective of a RexEx engine pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `RegExp` constructor:

```
text = text.replace(new RegExp(char, 'gi'), '');
```

**Worth noting**: **[some characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html)** have special meaning and need to be escaped to be treated literally (for example `.` must be written as `\.` to mean "literal dot" and not "any character".

Alternatively, join the array of characters, escape what needs escaping, and perform the replacement once:

```
const exceptionsCharClass = exceptions
  .map(char => char.replace(/[\.\-\]\[]/, '\\$1')) // escape . - [ and ]
  .join('');                                       // join
const exceptionsPattern = `[${exceptionCharClass}]`
// exceptionsPattern is now [t\.\-], which you can use to replace once instead of in a loop.
```

Comment: How did you manage to convert the Wiki answer to a regular answer? Because of the diamond?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, diamond perks. The answer was starting to get non-trivial, so I reversed the community wiki. Normal users can custom flag their own answers to remove CW status and in 99.99% of the cases, mods will comply.